# One Common View In Every ViewController

Tags: ios

I am having a hard time wording this when searching the internet so I am just going to ask the question.

I have an options view in my app that slides into view when the user clicks a button. This options view will display app information like settings. I want this options view to be displayed on every view controller in my app. I do not want to copy and paste the code for the options view into every viewcontroller file. The options view has quite a few outlets and actions and also calls many delegates.

How can I reuse this options view in all my view controllers without adding all the outlets, actions, and delegate methods each time?

I was going to make a new file with public methods, but I would still have to copy the outlets. Would this public methods file have to include delegate methods as well then?

Let me know if my question does not make sense. I am hoping there is a standard way of implementing something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have the options view be the view of an options view controller, and show it modally from any view controller you want. Is there some reason you're not doing it this way? This is the usual way to do this, not by having a view that you reuse in different controllers.

Comment: I did not even think about this, because I just had the options view as a subview in the ViewController. But this makes much more sense since this options view can obviously be separated out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add the options as a subview of the window, then make your App Delegate handle all of the options view's outlets

Comment: By window do you mean each view controller? You can put outlets in AppDelete and attach them to any view controller's objects? That's cool.

Comment: By window, I mean the app delegate's window object.  It is the primary "view" that all over view controllers are subviews of

Comment: Okay, so in general if I want all my view controllers in my storyboard to contain the same view with the same outlets and such I can just add it to AppDelegate? So creating this view in AppDelegate has to be done purely in code, without storyboard?